# Record the source filenames of each pattern retrieved from files in a directory

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I have a directory in which there are two files. Here are the contents of the files.

Text 1.txt

```
I_PP have_VHP black_JJ eyes_NNS ._SENT He_PP has_VHZ blue_JJ eyes_NNS ._SENT
```

Text 2.txt

```
I_PP have_VHP short_JJ hairs_NNS ._SENT She_PP has_VHZ long_JJ hairs_NNS ._SENT
```

And I want to extract the adjective + noun phrases from these two files. In addition, I want to locate each matched pattern in the source file by their filename. The output should be csv file like this:

```
filename    Matches
Text1.txt   black_JJ eyes_NNS
Text1.txt   blue_JJ eyes_NNS
Text2.txt   short_JJ hairs_NNS
Text2.txt   long_JJ hairs_NNS
```

I tried the following code. The extraction part worked. However, the code did not give me the filename column that I wanted.

```
path = './TEST'
words = []
for file in os.listdir(path):
    filename = []
    ANs = []
    for word in open(file):
        words.append(word.rstrip('\n'))
        text0 = " ".join(str(x) for x in words)
        text1 = text0.lower()
        ANs = re.findall(r'\w+\_j.{1,2}\s\w+\_n.{1,3}', text1)
        filename.append(os.path.basename(file))

columns = {"filename":filename,"Matches":ANs}

result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(columns, orient='index')
result1 = result.transpose()
result1.to_csv("./result.csv", sep=',', index=False)
```

Comment: What was preventing you from changing the code so that it gives you the filename column you want?

Comment: In the output csv file, the filename column was filled with the output filename "result.csv" instead of the source filenames. I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: What are the values of `filename` and `ANs` in the line `columns = ...`?